# Oracle MAF: Clicking on Input text fields in a dialogue popups causing random crashes under Windows 10 Anniversary Edition

Tags: textfield, windows-10-universal, oracle-maf

We have implemented a tablet-based application using Oracle MAF. The application runs on Windows UWP. When it was rolled out last year, it has been working fine until the customers upgraded Windows UWP on their laptops to Windows Anniversary edition. After some investigation, We found the following issues:

- When user clicks on input text fields in a popup dialogue, the
  application randomly crashes (not always but frequently).
- When user clicks on input text fields in a normal window (i.e. not in a popup dialogue), and if the screen resolution is scaled (e.g. 150%), the
  application also randomly crashes.
- When screen resolution is not scaled (i.e. 100%), clicking on input text fields in a normal window
  does not seem to cause crash. However, clicking on input text fields
  in a popup dialogue can still cause crash.
- We could not find any useful/relevant info in Windows log or in our application log.

We have also tested our application with the latest Windows Creator Edition and MAF 2.4.1, we found that the chances of random crashing seemed to have decreased, but crashing could still happen.

We have checked the Oracle MAF certification information at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/documentation/maf241certmatrix-3746359.html.
It states that "*Any tablet or desktop running Windows 10 with Intel processor*" are supported. Our customers' laptop specs are:

- Lenovo Yoga with Intel Core i5 processor;
- Windows 10 Anniversary Edition;
- Full High Resolution screen (1920x1080)

Therefore, we believe the customer laptops provide certified runtime environment for MAF applications.

We have researched various technical forums. There seems to be little information about using MAF under Windows UWP environment.
Because our application has been used in production, and the customer corporate mandate is to use Windows 10 Anniversary edition, the customer expressed grave concerns to us for choosing MAF as the mobile platform technology, and we are now under enormous pressure to fix this issue. Any suggestions and pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a reusable test case, my recommendation to you is to lodge a Service Request with Oracle Support so Oracle's development teams can look at this.

Comment: Thanks. The issue can be reproduced on Oracle's own CompGallery demo app, as detailed in my next post. We have raised a support case to the Oracle support.

Answer (score 0):

We have done further investigation on the issue "input text field causing crash on Windows 10 Anniversary Edition". This time we used the demo CompGallery application from Oracle. We navigated to the "text box" tab, clicked on the text box in "outside a form", entered some text, then clicked on "inside a form" text box. The application crashed (or repeat the above sequence a couple of times on Windows Creator Edition, the application would crash). Note by using "tab" key or screen tapping to navigate between input text fields, we can avoid crashing. With extra clicks on different input text fields before entering text, we can avoid crashing as well.

The CompGallery screen is shown below:
[image]

We then looked at the Windows log, not much details were revealed. It contains an event related to the failure of edgethtml.dll, as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]